# Problem installing VS 2008 due to Microsoft Document Explorer missing

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I attempted to install vs 2008 on a new lap top from HP. Every time i would run the install program and then run VS when attempting to use the help program it would lock up and error that MS Document Explorer was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried repairing the installation of VS 2008?

Go to "Add/Remove Programs" (XP) or "Programs and Features" (Vista+), find Visual Studio, click "Change", then follow the wizard and select "Repair Visual Studio".

Answer (score 0):

Following is a link to someone with the Document Explorer Bug who fixed it by uninstalling the partially installed Web Designer Tools.

**Before** you try this i would recommend trying to reinstall VS2008 with minimal features selected (and probably avoiding Web Designer Tools and other features that require Document Explorer).

> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vs2008prereleaseinstallandsetup/thread/0826a01e-0c22-49bc-aacc-d25dba2d1084

Answer (score 0):

After about 2 days of deleting, re-installing and reading numerous blogs on problems of this nature the install disk started to have problems installing. My final resolution of the problem was as follows.
 - Apparently the cd drives in new HP machines are purchased on price and are not really the best. I switched to copying the files over the network from my desktop cd drive (better quality) directly to my hard drive on the Laptop. Success file error got better but still had a few problems.
 - Determined that although you uninstall MSDN with the Autorun program on the CD, MS Document Explorer is not removed. I used the uninstall provided with W7 and removed it. Probably corrupt.
 - I used the uninstall of W7 and removed all traces of Norton, VS, MSDN, and anything else I could find that related to VS.
- I did not trust the Autorun program as it had failed when running from the hard drive so I installed VS by using the setup program. 
- I then installed MSDN by using the setup program in the MSDN folder.

No problems since even though I installed SP1.

Problem probably was caused initially by a cheap CD drive.

Cheers